# How client data will deserialize to model class when form post in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

suppose i have model class look like

```
public class Person
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50,ErrorMessage="Full name should be within 50 character")]
        public string full_name { get; set; }

        [Range(18,80)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide age")]
        public Int32 Age { get; set; }
    }
```

and i have form based on this model class

```
@{Html.BeginForm("PostData", "Customodelbinder");
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name : </td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBox("first_name")</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Middle Name : </td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBox("middle_name")</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Surname :</td>
                        <td> @Html.TextBox("last_name")</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age:</td>
                        <td> @Html.TextBox("age") </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            }
```

now i like to know when i will submit the form then PostData will be called and how data will automatically posted to Person model class from client side to server side

```
public void PostData(Person person)
{

}
```

i search google and found we need to use **ModelBinder** is it true ? when one should use **ModelBinder** ?

**http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/806415/Model-Binding-using-IModelBinder-and-DefaultModelB**

without using **ModelBinder** can't we post client side data to action method where action method will have person argument and automatically client side person data will be `de-serialize` to person class ??

please help me how to do it with & without model binder with some sample code. thanks

Comment: Why not just create a view model with the FirstName, MiddleName and LastName properties so the `DefaultModelBinder` will do it all for you?

Comment: Why would you ever want to not use the default model binder? That's one of the great features of the MVC Framework! If you don't want to bind to an object, just use parameters in your action and send the values trough the query string. Much more messy though...

Comment: can u plzz tell me in what kind of situation people extend the default model binder....just give me a sample scenario. i like to know when people would go for custom model binder ? thnaks

Comment: The default model binder is pretty powerful. I never had the need to extend it. I would suspect that one would extend it when the model would be a highly complex class, with complex properties, with multiple "level" (i.e. nested classes and properties).

Comment: [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i search google and found we need to use ModelBinder is it true ?

Partially, `DefaultModelBinder` does work well in most case where primitive and even complex types involved. So you don't need to consider writing ModelBinder in most cases. I have 6-8 controller and 150+ action and need not written a single binder.

```
when one should use ModelBinder ?
```

When the `DefaultModelBinder` is failing to bind your request data into the model. e.g. you are getting a request from a device that has typical format, security key, data, etc. `DefaultModelBinder` works on best case match i.e. it will look into you request params and try to find exact name in model, if a match is find, it will copy value in model.

```
without using ModelBinder can't we post client side data to action method where action method will have person argument and automatically client side person data will be de-serialize to person class ??
```

Sure you can, we all do that. Using AJAX post method. Pass the model data into the data property in ajax request. If you name your js model correctly, the data will be bind to controller action parameter perfectly. e.g.

```
var searchResultModel = { searchId: searchId, isSearchEdited: true };

    // Get the result view
    $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SearchResult", "Search")',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: JSON.stringify(searchResultModel)
    })
    .success(function (searchResult) {
        $('#contentLoader').html(searchResult);
    });
```

Comment: thanks for explanation. suppose if one request param name is FirstName and model has firstname....in this case do we need to have custom model binder ? or if request param name is FirstName & model has name property....then do we need to have custom model binder ? plzz guide. thanks

Comment: when u r working with mvc then i like to ask onething that when we work with asp.net webform then we could have many user control in same page and data persist during postback when any user controls causes form post. in web form viewstate save our life but if we have many partial view with their form and one of the form causes post data to server side then i like to know when data comes back from server to client then how other forms in other partial view will persist their data? guide best practice to handle this kind of situation. thanks

Comment: For your first comment, the model binder expects property names to follow the form post naming syntax, regardless of whether the request is a GET or a POST. JSON requests have the same requirements. It means you ought to use the same property name both at client and server.

Comment: For your second question, I see the confusion when transitioning from webform. Basically, in the case you explained, I would keep the data in a parent model (model class will contain other child object). Each partial view get its on model object and update it. Its difficult to explain in comment, if required please post a question. Hope this helps :)